# Set image of uiButton in custom table cell

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have a uitbutton within a custom table cell. I am trying to set the buttons image with

```
[cell.thumbImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"full_breakfast.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

It is displaying a blue button instead of the image like so:

[image]

Am I doing this wrong? When i remove the `uibutton setImage` it returns to the normal button. This SHOULD be fairly simple so sorry if it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In iOS7 there is new button type called UIButtonTypeSystem NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0), // standard system button

Check your .xib file and change button type to Custom, or programatically you can do this:

[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];

Comment: Cheers, no problem my friend.